# SVG tag text Cannot set property button

Tags: javascript, svg

I try to set the property button or top, but if i call the function collision with the first button with the script inside html works good.

But if i try with the second button to call the same function inside at the app.js file, like the second example i show below i receive the error : *TypeError: Cannot set property bottom of # which has only a getter*

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> D3.js Demo Example</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>First html document</h1>

<p>This is my first sentence</p>

<svg width="500" height="400">
  <text x="50" y="50">ciao come</text>
  <text x="70" y="60">elefante testo 3</text>
  <text x="30" y="40">leone testa di minchia</text>
  <text x="90" y="20">pippo testo 4</text>
  <text x="50" y="70">bruno testo 5</text>
  <text x="80" y="40">silente testo 3</text>
  <!-- Add more <text> elements as needed -->
</svg>

<button onclick="collision()">click inside function</button>

<button id="btn">CLick event listener</button>

 <script  data-mt-widget-pagelanguage="fr" data-mt-widget-site="patentscope" id="taptaWidgetUrl" src="dist/app.js"></script>
 
<script>
function collision(){

const svg = d3.select("svg");
let hasCollisions = true;

while (hasCollisions) {
  hasCollisions = false;

  const textElements = svg.selectAll("text");

  textElements.each(function () {
    const textElement = d3.select(this);
    const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

    textElements.each(function () {
      if (this !== textElement.node()) {
        const otherRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (rect.bottom > otherRect.top && rect.top < otherRect.bottom) {
          const yOffset = Math.max(0, otherRect.bottom - rect.top + 5); // Add padding
          textElement.attr("y", parseFloat(textElement.attr("y")) + yOffset);
          rect.bottom += yOffset;
          rect.top += yOffset;
          hasCollisions = true;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the example with the code inside app.js, in this casei receive the error: *TypeError: Cannot set property bottom of # which has only a getter*

```
"use strict";
var bt = document.getElementById('btn');
bt.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  collisionAvoid();
}, false);


function collisionAvoid(){
  //var svgObject = document.querySelectorAll(".atac-svg-tranlator");
  //var svgDocument = svgObject[0].contentDocument;
  
  //const svg = d3.select(svgDocument).select("svg");
  const svg = d3.select("svg");
  console.log("rect", svg)
  let hasCollisions = true;
  
  while (hasCollisions) {
    hasCollisions = false;
  
    const textElements = svg.selectAll("text");
  
    textElements.each(function () {
      const textElement = d3.select(this);
      const rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  
      textElements.each(function () {
        if (this !== textElement.node()) {
          const otherRect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
  
          if (rect.bottom > otherRect.top && rect.top < otherRect.bottom) {
            const yOffset = Math.max(0, otherRect.bottom - rect.top + 5); // Add padding
            textElement.attr("y", parseFloat(textElement.attr("y")) + yOffset);
            rect.bottom += yOffset;
            rect.top += yOffset;
            hasCollisions = true;
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
}
```

Comment: First suggestion is to step through the code to determine which line in your jss produces the error.Then get back to us.

Comment: @Nikkorian the error it come  when i try to set the property bottom, rect.bottom += yOffset;

Answer (score 0):

You have defined rect as a constant. You should change

```
const rect;
```

to

```
let rect;
```

so it can be modified.

EDIT
More importantly, here's what the .getBoundingClientRect() method returns: "a DOMRect object *providing information* about the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport". So your "const rect" is a read-only object. Its properties will changes as the textElement that it's describing changes, but *you cannot change it* directly. See https://jsfiddle.net/Nikkorian/pmf5vy97/4/

My guess is that the reason you get an error in the dist/app.js is that this is using strict mode. If you put

```
"use strict";
```

as the first line in your 'inside' < script > section, you will get the same result. In its current form, your 'inside' function is just ignoring the error.

I do not know d3. But I suggest that if your inside function is working while ignoring the error, then it's probable that you could remove the lines

```
 rect.bottom += yOffset;
 rect.top += yOffset;
```

altogether. They are probably not doing anything except triggering exceptions.

Comment: it does not work same Error:  TypeError: Cannot set property bottom of #<DOMRectReadOnly> which has only a getter

Comment: @corsaro OK I rushed that off - my bad. I will edit my answer to give a more considered response.